# Keep br tags from stripping

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, actions, wp-autop

Is there some filter to disable this, sometimes awful feature?

I need content of some custom post type to be displayed intact, with all of `<br>`s.

To get the content I'm using `get_the_content();` inside of `WP_Query` loop, inside of shortcode function.

I'm grateful with any clue, but answer without the word "plugin" would blow my mind.

Comment: You can add some classname to the br tag, WP won't strip tags with classes. For example use `<br class="wpse-break" >`

Comment: @bravokeyl yes, thanks, that is also true for attributes `[data-anything]`. It's odd, though, and I would really wish that I could specify: "ok WP, don't touch anything for this types of posts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since any attribute added to `<br>` tag, including class names and `data-attr`s keeps them from stripping, quick and incomplete way could be:

```
function filter_function_name( $content, $post_id ) {

  $content = str_replace('<br>', '<br data-x>',   $content);
  $content = str_replace('<br >', '<br data-x>',  $content);
  $content = str_replace('<br />', '<br data-x>', $content);
  $content = str_replace('<br/>', '<br data-x>',  $content);

  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'content_edit_pre', 'filter_function_name', 10, 2 );
```